# TypeError: Action failed: [component.find(...).filter is not a function]

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex-code, salesforce-lightning, aura-framework

Getting  TypeError: Action failed:  [component.find(...).filter is not a function] in below code

```
isFormValid: function (component) {
    
    return (component.find('requiredField'))
   .filter(function (i) {
        var value = i.get('v.value');
        console.log('Emailissue' + value);
        return !value || value == '' || value.trim().length === 0;
    })
    .map(function (i) {
        return i.get('v.fieldName');
    });
    
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you display the field(s) conditionally? Wrapper in `<aura:if isTrue=...>` tag maybe?
Your `find` returned a single record with that `aura:id` (so there's no "filter" on it, it's a single object, not an array) or it haven't found anything at all.

Go to setup -> debug mode, enable it for yourself and add `debugger;` to this code (or add a watch/breakpoint from the browser's F12 console)

Comment: I am getting single records from this code

Comment: A single record or an array with 1 element? Sounds like single record. Since there's nothing to loop over/filter - try `var value = component.find('requiredField').get('v.value');`